# How to correctly determine whether a post-type is active in a given blog in a wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, multisite

If I register a post type for example like this:

```php
function setup_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'public'    => true,
        'label'     => __( 'Recipe', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book',
    );
   
    // Should only be active in a given blog
    if( get_current_blog_id() === 14 ) {
        register_post_type( 'recipe', $args );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'setup_post_type' );
```

it will only be available in the backend of the given blog with ID 14. However, when trying to determine whether the post-type is active in another blog - for example for building hreflang links for post archives - you get the following:

So let's say you visit blog with ID 14:

```php
    var_dump(get_current_blog_id()); // 14
    var_dump(post_type_exists('recipe')); // true
    switch_to_blog(15);
    var_dump(post_type_exists('recipe')); // true
    restore_current_blog();
```

But if you visit the blog with ID 15 you will get the following:

```php
    var_dump(get_current_blog_id()); // 15
    var_dump(post_type_exists('recipe')); // false
    switch_to_blog(14);
    var_dump(post_type_exists('recipe')); // false
    restore_current_blog();
```

As the posts are registered in wordpress' `init` hook they're now available depending on where you started loading the site and the dependency will not be re-evaluated.

Is there a way to correctly determine post-type existence on other blogs?

Comment: Because you start out with blog id 14 the post type will be registered, also when you switch blog later on. This is because the post type is registered before you switch to blog id 15

Comment: Yes I am aware of the fact that this is why I get the same booleans depending on where you load the application. But the question is - what to do?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that it's impossible. Why do you want to do this? You register the post type to blog 14 hard-coded so you'll know for sure for which blog it's registered. Or do you want to do it dynamically?

Comment: This is just a simplified example for a bigger multisite I am working on with different sets of post types in each language. I am actually managing post types via backend setting, so there would be an option I can check manually instead, but I was wondering if there is a way it's supposed to be done as this only works until some other developer comes around and adds post types in a different fashion.

Comment: There is a bit of a [related discussion in Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35603) for this that was closed because the poster wanted something very specific that might break the world for the other 99%, and no one was really interested in dealing with posts types in a `switch_to_blog` context.